# Defining scope for function in module

Tags: powershell, scope

We have the following two files:

**Script A**

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

Import-ParamsTestHC -source 'Bananas'

Write-Verbose 'Script A needs Bananas:'
$EventParams

&'S:\Test\Brecht\Testie5.ps1'

Write-Verbose 'Script A needs Bananas:'
$EventParams
```

**Script B:**

```
Write-Verbose 'Script B needs Apples'

Import-ParamsTestHC -source 'Apples'
$EventParams
```

**Module file with function:**

```
Function Import-ParamsTestHC {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Source
    )

    $Global:EventParams = @{
        Fruit = $Source
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
VERBOSE: Script A needs Bananas:

Name                           Value                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                       
Fruit                          Bananas                                                                                     
VERBOSE: Script B needs Apples
Fruit                          Apples                                                                                      
VERBOSE: Script A needs Bananas:
Fruit                          Apples
```

**Desired output:**

```
VERBOSE: Script A needs Bananas:

Name                           Value                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                       
Fruit                          Bananas                                                                                     
VERBOSE: Script B needs Apples
Fruit                          Apples                                                                                      
VERBOSE: Script A needs Bananas:
Fruit                          Bananas
```

We're trying to import parameters for splatting in both scripts. But it seems hard to have a scope specific for that script. Is there a way around this?

When we try changing the global scope `$Global:EventParams` to a script scope `$Script:EventParams` the variables are totally not available.

Comment: Of course it's always possible to import the function again, after script B has ran. But I thought my usage of scope was incorrect and there's maybe a better way.

Comment: Rewrite `Import-ParamsTestHC` to return value, and `$EventParams = Import-ParamsTestHC` in main script.

Comment: I assume **S:\Test\Brecht\Testie5.ps1** is Script B?

Comment: Correct, that is Script B.Returning values is difficult as there are multiple hash tables in that function which are all used for splatting.

Comment: `$PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set( 'EventParams', @{ Fruit = $Source
 } )`